# Time not getting converted to local time properly via moment.js

Tags: javascript, c#, momentjs, utc

```
11-06-2015 12:44:30
```

My datetime has the above format however it isn't getting converted to Local Time it gives me the month as November instead.

```
var check = moment('@Model.Invoice.InvoiceDate').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

                    var localTime = moment.utc(check).toDate();
                    localTime = moment(localTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

                    console.log(localTime);
```

White saving i am using DateTime.UTCNow function of C# and while getting the data i am using the following code.

Code:

```
 var formatDate = new Date('@Model.Invoice.InvoiceDate.ToLocalTime()');
                    console.log(formatDate);
                    formatDate = moment.utc(formatDate).toDate();
                    console.log(formatDate);
                    var dateTime = moment(formatDate).format('lll');
                    console.log(dateTime);
```

Example of what is happening:

```
  var formatDate = new Date('Sat Jun 13 2015 13:00:11 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)');
                            console.log(formatDate);
                            formatDate = moment.utc(formatDate).toDate();
                            console.log(formatDate);
                            var dateTime = moment(formatDate).format('lll');
                            console.log(dateTime);
```

Comment: You can also solve this without moment.js, by using native method of javascript Date object. Checkout this link --- http://praveenlobo.com/techblog/how-to-convert-javascript-local-date-to-utc-and-utc-to-local-date/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print an UTC ISO 8601 date for moment with ToString("s") but it will lack the Z, so you need to add it yourself.

`var localTime = moment('@String.concat(Model.Invoice.InvoiceDate.ToString("s"), "Z")').format('lll');`

Or by adding the Z on client side :

`var localTime = moment('@Model.Invoice.InvoiceDate.ToString("s")' + 'Z').format('lll');`

Comment: My Object is a DateTime field and not string

Comment: That's why there is a ToString("s"), it converts your DateTime to an ISO8601 Date String and .net implementation lacks the 'Z' so the concat adds it.

Comment: Can i do something like this: Convert.ToDateTime(string.Concat(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("s"), "Z"))

Comment: Just replace my DateTime with your DateTime object and put the result in your template.

Comment: Something like this : string.Concat(Model.Invoice.InvoiceDate.UtcNow.ToString("s"), "Z")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80475/discussion-between-vini-and-pierre-inglebert).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var check = moment('11-06-2015 12:44:30', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss')
                    .format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

or in your case this

```
var check = moment('@Model.Invoice.InvoiceDate', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss')
                    .format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

instead of

```
var check = moment('@Model.Invoice.InvoiceDate')
                   .format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

While giving moments a date string you need to specify which part is what.

Comment: What if the time format changes? Now my server date time looks like this: 6/12/2015

Comment: While saving i am using c# so i am doing DateTime.UTCNow